# Parsing recursive structure on boost::spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I won to parse structure like "text { < > }". Spirit documentation contents similar [AST](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___asts_.html) example. 
For parsing string like this

```
<tag1>text1<tag2>text2</tag1></tag2>
```

this code work:

```
    templ     = (tree | text)       [_val = _1];

    start_tag = '<' 
            >> !lit('/') 
            >> lexeme[+(char_- '>') [_val += _1]] 
            >>'>'; 

    end_tag   =  "</" 
            >> string(_r1) 
            >> '>'; 

    tree =  start_tag          [at_c<1>(_val) = _1]
            >> *templ          [push_back(at_c<0>(_val), _1) ]
            >> end_tag(at_c<1>(_val) )
            ;
```

For parsing string like this

```
<tag<tag>some_text>
```

This code not work:

```
    templ     = (tree | text)       [_val = _1];


    tree =  '<'
            >> *templ          [push_back(at_c<0>(_val), _1) ]
            >> '>'
            ;
```

templ is parsing structure with recursive_wrapper inside:

```
namespace client {

   struct tmp;

   typedef boost::variant <
        boost::recursive_wrapper<tmp>,
        std::string
   > tmp_node;

   struct tmp {
     std::vector<tmp_node> content;
     std::string text;
   };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
     tmp_view::tmp,
     (std::vector<tmp_view::tmp_node>, content)
     (std::string,text)
)
```

Who may explain why it happened? Maybe who knows similar parsers wrote on boost::spirit?

Comment: What is the question? I see two invalid XML snippets, and two relatively unrelated grammars that both obviously should not parse the invalid XML. I've written a lot of parsers in Spirit. Perhaps they were similar. But you forgot to mention "what happened" (so we can't say "why it happened") and you also forgot to say what you are trying to achieve. So _who knows_ there are similar parsers...

Comment: I'll forget a text rule. In second case(working) it must be "text = lexeme[+(char_ - '<' - '>')      [_val += _1]];"

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing you didn't actually want to parse XML at all, but rather some kind of mixed-content markup language for hierarchical text, I'd do

```
        simple = +~qi::char_("><");
        nested = '<' >> *soup >> '>';
        soup   = nested|simple;
```

With the AST/rules defined as

```
typedef boost::make_recursive_variant<
        boost::variant<std::string, std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_> > 
    >::type tag_soup;

qi::rule<It, std::string()>           simple;
qi::rule<It, std::vector<tag_soup>()> nested;
qi::rule<It, tag_soup()>              soup;
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3216834957b29173)**:

```
////  #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

namespace client
{
    typedef boost::make_recursive_variant<
            boost::variant<std::string, std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_> > 
        >::type tag_soup;

    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    template <typename It>
    struct parser : qi::grammar<It, tag_soup()>
    {
        parser() : parser::base_type(soup)
        {
            simple = +~qi::char_("><");
            nested = '<' >> *soup >> '>';
            soup   = nested|simple;

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((simple)(nested)(soup))
        }
      private:
        qi::rule<It, std::string()>           simple;
        qi::rule<It, std::vector<tag_soup>()> nested;
        qi::rule<It, tag_soup()>              soup;
    };
}

namespace boost { // leverage ADL on variant<>
    static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<client::tag_soup> const& soup)
    {
        os << "<";
        std::copy(soup.begin(), soup.end(), std::ostream_iterator<client::tag_soup>(os));
        return os << ">";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "Error: No input file provided.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
    std::string const storage(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in), {}); // We will read the contents here.

    if (!(in || in.eof())) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not read from input file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    static const client::parser<std::string::const_iterator> p;

    client::tag_soup ast; // Our tree
    bool ok = parse(storage.begin(), storage.end(), p, ast);

    if (ok) std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\nData: " << ast << "\n";
    else    std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";

    return ok? 0 : 1;
}
```

If you define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG you'll get verbose output of the parsing process.

For the input

```
<some text with nested <tags <etc...> >more text>
```

prints

```
Parsing succeeded
Data: <some text with nested <tags <etc...> >more text>
```

Note that the output is printed from the variant, not the original text.

Comment: I debuged parser. How used more than one tag type ('<','>'). For example "<text{text1<>text2<>}>". How in place with close tag ('>','}') parser knows what tag open expression (in mini_xml example using reference).

Comment: @crastinus You still need to tell us what you are trying to achieve. I can "parse" those tags just fine without even using Spirit. (`cat input.txt > /dev/null` that is, if there's no desired/required behaviour).

Comment: thanks for help. No matter i want. I just understood that unimportant what tag open or close.